# Rails app deployment, rake DB:migrate doesn't create table and want table to already be here to create them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, production

Server ubuntu 64b
App using rails 3.1
database mysql

Now rails db:create works fine

Rails db:migrate done manually or through cap deploy:migration give me the following error :

> rake aborted!
>   Mysql2::Error: Table 'mywebsite_production.galleries' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `galleries`
>   /srv/d_mywebsite/www/mywebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:283:in `query'

What is wrong in this deployment ?

Answer (score 2):

I just comment out the device and `rails_admin` routes on my `config/routes.rb` and everything worked out. Check if any of your routes are requiring the existence of`mywebsite_production.galleries`.

Comment: I was struggling exactly same error. I was using routes that required existence of a table. Once I commented them out, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems:

1. While manually creating the database, you probably didn't name it properly.
2. Or, because you said that `db:create` was failing, another problem could be that Rails or your database aren't set up properly and thus can't communicate with each other.

I would advice you to investigate the `db:create` issue first, this is likely the same thing that causes `db:migrate` to fail.

By creating the database yourself, all you've done is move the problem up in the stack, and once you manage to manually fix the migration issues, you might run into more problems down the road.

Comment: I tried so many thing so i did a mistake, actually rails db:create does work. i eddited my question

Answer (score 0):

can you all load all table names and check if table you created manually is present it list?

you can list table names using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables`